# How to get IMEI Number | IONIC | Android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2, imei

I need to fetch the IMEI from Android device, i am working in an IONIC App.

I am using this plugin - `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-uid`

Reference link - https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/uid/

Here is my code snippet -

```
async getIMEI() {

    const {hasPermission} = await this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(
        this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_PHONE_STATE
    );

    console.log("hasPermission : " + hasPermission);
    if (!hasPermission) {
        const result = await this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(
            this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_PHONE_STATE
        );

        if (!result.hasPermission) {
            throw new Error('Permissions required');
        }

        // ok, a user gave us permission, we can get him identifiers after restart app
        return 0 ;
    }

    return this.uid.IMEI;
}
```

I am calling getIMEI() in constructor  -

```
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public alertCtrl: AlertController,
                public apiProvider: ApiProvider, public storage: Storage, public platform: Platform, public fcm: FCM,
                public uid: Uid, public androidPermissions: AndroidPermissions) {


        platform.ready().then(() => {

            if (this.platform.is('android')) {
                console.log("running on Android device!");
                this.deviceType = 'ANDROID';
                this.getIMEI();
            }
            if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
                console.log("running on iOS device!");
                this.deviceType = 'IPHONE';
            }



        });
    }
```

I am always getting IMEI number as **null** value.

Comment: did you find a solution for this??

Comment: Same problem: any updates?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/uid

First add the plugin to you app:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-uid
npm install @ionic-native/uid
```

In the ts file you want to get IMEI:

```
import { Uid } from '@ionic-native/uid/ngx';
import { AndroidPermissions } from '@ionic-native/android-permissions/ngx';

constructor(private uid: Uid, private androidPermissions: AndroidPermissions) { }


async getImei() {
 const { hasPermission } = await this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(
   this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_PHONE_STATE
 );

 if (!hasPermission) {
   const result = await this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(
     this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_PHONE_STATE
   );

   if (!result.hasPermission) {
     throw new Error('Permissions required');
   }

   // ok, a user gave us permission, we can get him identifiers after restart app
   return;
 }

  return this.uid.IMEI
}
```

Comment: For ionic v4 https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/uid and ionic v3  https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/uid/